# The characteristic function $\chi_E$ is a continuous function on $X$ iff $E$ is simultaneously an open set and a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered a problem:

> $E\subset X$ ,Prove the characteristic function $\chi_E$ is a continuous function on $X$ iff $E$ is simultaneously an open set and a closed set.

I think that if $\chi_E$ is a continuous funtion, then the only possibility for $E$ is that $E=X$ or $E=\emptyset$ . So is this question's answer is just as simple as I think? Or there are some points that I overlooked? Any help and hints will be appreciated!

Best regards!

Comment: The problem is correct and you are overlooking something. Just directly apply the definition of continuity and see what you get.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh I get it, from the definition I can conclude that both $E$ and $E^C$ are open sets, right?

Comment: Yes, and that's all that's required.